# Print string with new lines aligned in Python

Tags: python, string, printing, format, newline

Is there an easy way to print a string that contains a new line `\n`, aligned to the left after a certain number of characters?

Basically, what I have is something like

```
A = '[A]: '
B = 'this is\na string\nwith a new line'

print('{:<10} {}'format(A, B))
```

The problem is that with the new line, the next lines do not start at the 10th column:

```
[A]:       this is
a string
with a new line
```

I would like something like

```
[A]:       this is
           a string
           with a new line
```

I could maybe split `B`, but I was wondering if there was an optial way of doing this

Comment: What about replacing the `'\n'` with `'\n          '`? (including 10 spaces).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is replacing a new line with a new line and 11 (11 because of the 10 in `{:<10}` but you add an additional space in your format) spaces:

```
B2 = B.replace('\n','\n           ')
print('{:<10} {}'.format(A, B2))
```

Or perhaps more elegantly:

```
B2 = B.replace('\n','\n'+11*' ')
print('{:<10} {}'.format(A, B2))
```

Running this in `python3`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> A = '[A]: '
>>> B = 'this is\na string\nwith a new line'
>>> B2 = B.replace('\n','\n           ')
>>> print('{:<10} {}'.format(A, B2))
[A]:       this is
           a string
           with a new line
```

Comment: you should change 10 spaces to 9 because of space after ":" in A

Comment: @latsha: euh shouldn't it be 11, I've counted the number of spaces per new line based on the last fragment in the question.

Comment: anyway you can test it out