# How to align Output in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am sure this is a duplicate question. However I wasn't able to find that directed me correctly.
I am new so would appreciate any help available.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])

print(df)

print("df.iloc[0]['x']:", df.iloc[0]['x'])

print(f'''df.iloc[0]: {df.iloc[0]}''')
```

prints

```
x    y
A  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN
C  NaN  NaN
df.iloc[0]['x']: nan
df.iloc[0]: x    NaN
y    NaN
Name: A, dtype: object

[Program finished]
```

A similar question but with numpy has already been answered.
Now the question is how should I get the prefix aligned in the third output?
The numpy equivalent for similar is

```
print("Array:", np.array2string(array1, prefix ='Array:'))
```

Edit 1:
Expected Output :

```
df.iloc[0]: x    NaN
            y    NaN
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: I didn't get it what do you mean by aligned?

Comment: posted expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing `\n` with spaces:

```
p = df.iloc[0].to_string().replace('\n','\n'+' '*12)
print('{:<11} {}'.format('df.iloc[0]:',p))
```

---

```
df.iloc[0]: x    NaN
            y    NaN
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673689/print-string-with-new-lines-aligned-in-python)

[formating info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103221/6660373)

Comment: I might sound noob but is that a syntax or you actually Counted till 12

Comment: @Subham: If there is a longer string then it will fail. yeah you are right I manually set it to 12 by counting.

Comment: @Subham: There is no other solution than this.